# GitHub Pages - " Your site is having problems building: Page build failed."

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, mkdocs

I'm trying to troubleshoot a GitHub Pages failure. The Github Actions workflow completes successfully, and I can see that mkdocs has successfully updated the `gh-pages` branch. I've also confirmed that I can run `mkdocs serve` locally with a successful build.

After the workflow completes, I can go into the repository settings, into the GitHub Pages tab, and see the "Your site is having problems building: Page build failed." error, but no further context on what is causing it to fail.

Another interesting note, if I create a `gh-pages-test` branch from the `gh-pages` branch and then change the source value to the new test branch, I get a successful deployment. I can then switch back to the regular branch and it will also deploy successfully. If I run the GitHub Action workflow again though, the action succeeds but the page build fails.

This was working fine up until a week or two ago, but I'm not seeing any new changes in our code base that would have caused this. Is there any way to get more information on why it is failing?

Comment: Page builds have moved to all using GitHub Actions now. Do you see anything useful in the output of the workflows under the "Actions" tab?

Comment: The workflow completes successfully. There were some warnings in there regarding broken links that I went through and resolved, but now the output is clean and finishes with a message like:
```
   32e9505..012c396  gh-pages -> gh-pages
INFO     -  Your documentation should be available shortly.
```

It's only when I go into Settings->Github Pages that I see an error "Your site is having problems building: Page build failed." Unfortunately this error is very generic so it doesn't give me many troubleshooting options.

Comment: And you use the [publish from a branch](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch) method, or do you use a [custom GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow) to publish?

Comment: One thing I can think of: if you use the "publish from a branch" method, GitHub assumes you have a Jekyll site, but it looks like you use mkdocs instead. You have to have a `.nojekyll` file in your publishing source for that (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#troubleshooting-publishing-from-a-branch)).

Comment: We are using a custom GitHub Action to publish the site from a branch. Essentially, the GitHub Action uses mkdocs to generate the static files and check them into the `gh-pages` branch. GitHub then publishes the page based on the update to that source `gh-pages` branch

I had seen a note about the `.nojekyll` file during my troubleshooting research but found that it already exists in our gh-pages branch.

Comment: We're using GitHub Enterprise Server 3.5.1, so publishing from a source branch is the only option available. We don't yet have the GitHub Actions deployment options that have recently been made available in standard GitHub.

Comment: Ah, you're on Enterprise Server. I can't think of anything else that would cause this problem, I'm afraid. Maybe change permanently to a different branch as the publishing source, if that fixes it?

Comment: @ChrisBatchelor if you find a solution to this can you please share it here? 
I am also facing the same issue on GitHub Enterprise Server 3.5.1.

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan we haven't tried this yet (still sticking to the manual workaround mentioned in the original post), but it sounds as though this is a known issue and the following workaround has been suggested:

"GitHub is aware of the issue and their suggested workaround strategy is deleting the gh-pages branch and pushing to it again. Maybe for now, you could incorporate that strategy into your Actions workflow as a temporary fix. I will continue to work with GitHub to try to get to the bottom of the issue."

Comment: @ChrisBatchelor Thank you for the update! To get around the issue I added the following flow in actions: delete gh-pages branch then run mkdocs gh-deploy then run curl POST to enable github pages again on branch gh-pages. This way we have no manual interaction the only downside is that there is still down time of a minute or so for the action to execute and the pages to be re-enabled. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pages#create-a-github-pages-site